# How do I add a member (name and email address) to an existing Outlook Distribution List using C#

Tags: outlook, distribution-list

I am trying to programmatically add a member (name and email address) to an existing Outlook Distribution List, but I can figure out how to grab it.  I have found many postings describing how to create a new Outlook Distribution List, but none on how to add a member to an existing one.  I have been able to retrieve the items collection of the Contacts folder, but I cannot access the Outlook Distribution List I want.  Keep in mind that the Contacts folder contains at least two different object types, Contact Items and Distribution List items.  Is there a way to just retrieve the Distribution List items from the Contacts folder?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I have no code worth posting.

I have made some progress.  I now have the below code:

```
Outlook.MAPIFolder outlookContactsFolder = outlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts); // Get Contacts folder.
Outlook.Items outlookContactsItems = outlookContactsFolder.Items; // Get the Items collection.

for (int i = 1; i <= outlookContactsItems.Count; i++)
{
    if (i == 62)
    {
        Outlook.DistListItem outlookDistListItem = outlookContactsItems.GetNext();
        Outlook.Recipient outlookRecipient = **(Need help creating a Recipient object with a name and email address)**
        outlookDistListItem.AddMember(outlookRecipient);
        outlookDistListItem.Save();
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        Outlook.ContactItem outlookContactsItem = outlookContactsItems.GetNext();
    }
}
```

I know this is not the best way, but it works.  I can now access the Distribution List without the code blowing up.  Now I need to add a new member to it.  I know I can do that with the AddMember method, but it takes an Outlook.Recipient object.  I can't find anywhere how to create it with a name and email address.

Comment: So your question is really how to open an existing distribution list? What do you know about it? Entry id? Name? Etc.?

Comment: All I know is the name of the Distribution List.  Please look at my question again.  I have added more to it.